# part of a sentence is missing

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

Today I came across a question where some part of a sentence is missing.

```
If she ____ the calibration of the machine she ____ done the experiment.
```

Three options are given as follows:

```
1. knew, had
2. had known, could have
3. knows, will have
```

I'm confused between option i) & ii). Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! If you can tell us exactly **why** these options confuse you we will be happy to help you.

Comment: I can't exactly say why ... but i) and ii) are appearing quite usual and hence causing ambiguity.

Comment: Better to tell us what you think you understand from the sentence, rather than the options. That will help you and us! For example: Is it still possible to do the experiment? Was the machine calibrated?

Comment: The **Very Short Answer** is this: Which answer is correct depends on how far along you are in the study of English. If you have only recently started to learn English conditional constructions, it is almost certain that your teacher wants you to say that **ii.** is the correct answer. Eventually, however, you will discover that **any** of these could be correct in some circumstances.

Comment: You may find [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) helpful for your next question. "I'm confused" can be hard to answer; "I'm confused _because_..." often helps your question be more well-received.

Answer (score 1):

> She *knew* the calibration of the machine; she *had* done the experiment.

That's option (i), and it's grammatical. However, there's that little 2-little word at the front:

> If she *knew* the calibration of the machine, she *had* done the experiment.

That 2-letter word is called a conditional, and it often affects the tense and meanings of the verbs that follow. The resulting sentence here is grammatical, but it's awkward, and probably not expressing what the author intends. It means, essentially: *There is no way should could know the calibration of the machine unless she had done the experiment.*

Now let's use option (ii):

> If she *had known* the calibration of the machine she *could have* done the experiment.

This one means what the author is trying to say: *She could have done the experiment, if she had known the calibration of the machine* (with the likely implication: *However, since she did note know the machine's calibration, the experiment was not done at that time*).

This construct in English is called Type 3 Conditional. [One website](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-conditionals.php#.UxROf14YKR4) describes it as the situation where:

> It is impossible that the condition will be met because it refers to the past.
>   **Form:**
>   **∙** `if + Past Perfect, + would + have + Past Participle`
>   **Use:**
>   **∙** Conditional Sentences Type 3 refer to situations in the past. They express hypothetical results to past given situations.
>   **Example:**
>   *If he had been careful, he wouldn't have had that terrible accident*.

I'm almost certain your test problem was designed to reinforce the Type 3 conditional.

If you had Googled "Type 3 conditional sentences", you would have found plenty of other examples. (That's not a scolding; it's just an extra example. Here's [a link](https://www.google.com/#q=%22type+3+conditional+sentences%22) to get you started.)